# Downsizing from 256GB to 128GB iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, backup

I've been given a new phone (128GB iPhone 13) from work but it has half the storage of my last one (256GB iPhone 11). I have both here with me and the SIM is in the old one.

My old phone has pushed all photos to iCloud and almost filled my 200GB account. I have selected 'Optimise iPhone Storage' so these photos are not on my phone now. Settings -> General -> iPhone Storage reports that I am using 55.3GB of 256, so I expected to be able to do a straight copy from phone to phone.

So I place them next to each other and start, after going through minutes and minutes of confirmation, face scanning, options etc, it eventually says the new phone doesn't have enough space for all the data. Since 55.3 is substantially less than 128 I don't know what the problem is.

Apple's docs claim this is possible https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202961, does anyone have any advice?

Update: I have done a local backup and it is 144GB despite my iPhone saying it is only using 55GB. I suspect that the Phone Storage as reported by iOS doesn't count a load of photos that are in iCloud and on my phone which the local backup are transfer counting. So I need a way for the old iPhone to not include the photos that should be up on iCloud in the transfer across to the new phone

iCloud 200GB almost full

[image: iCloud usage]

Old iPhone claims to only use 55GB

[image: iPhone usage]

Backup on my Mac takes 144GB

[image: Local backup]

Comment: Please break up the _wall-of-text_ with some _paragraphs_ so it easier to read.

Comment: You have almost used all your 200gb of iCloud space.  200gb can't be put on a 128gb device so iCloud is telling you this can't be done.

Comment: @fsb Presumably optimize storage is on in photos, which would make that totally possible.

Comment: The simplest answer is probably to spend a couple dollars and get a month of 2TB iCloud Storage to complete a backup with. If this is not an option I can try to put other ideas here.

Comment: You're making incorrect assumptions on the size of your iCloud data.

Comment: @fsb I don't believe I am making any assumptions about anything. I've got a 200GB iCloud account. It is holding 184GB of photos that due to 'Optimise iPhone Storage' are not stored on my old phone. The old iPhone claims to only be using 55GB, I want to move that on to 128GB device.

Comment: @Ezekiel I got it to do a backup overnight and it claims it is only 2.29GB, so it clearly can't be backing up the 55GB the phone claims to be using, (or just the 11GB of Documents & Data according to OS X)

Comment: When you go to Settings -> your name -> iCloud, how much total space is displayed under 'Storage'?  If that total number (not just Photos) is greater than 128gb then you can't move it to your new device.

Comment: @Craig Backups don't include app downloads, only app data. This means games will take a lot of space but little in the backup. Consider restoring this backup and analyzing the usage on the new iPhone.

Comment: @fsb The total iCloud size is 192GB out of 200GB (184 of that is photos), but I'm not trying to copy all of that on to my 128GB phone. I'm expecting to copy 55GB from one phone to another and for the new one to have access to the same iCloud account, paired to the same watch, etc. As linked above, Apple claim this is possible but in practice it is saying it is not.

Comment: Please update your question to included the steps you're taking to eliminate all iCloud content except your Photos.  It appears (from the way your question is currently written) that you're not "optimizing or removing existing content" from storage.

Comment: @fsb I've made that update now. I skipped explaining before because the iPhone used size was 55 and iCloud photos was nearly 200.

Comment: iTunes/Finder backups do not contain iCloud Photos contents, so that isn't it unfortunately. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204136

Comment: Have you tried restoring the iCloud Backup to the new phone to examine whether it's complete?